# How to change the point size for regplot(), seaborn's scatter plot function (python)

Tags: python, seaborn

I want to be able to set the point size when plotting like this:

```
sns.regplot(y=[1,3,4,2,5], x=[range(5)], data=df,
            marker='o', color='red')
plt.show()
```

Do you guys know how?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To do this you can feed the `regplot()` function the `scatter_kws` arg like so:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.regplot(x='total_bill', y='tip', data=tips,
            marker='o', color='red', scatter_kws={'s':2})
```

[image: small points]

```
sns.regplot(x='total_bill', y='tip', data=tips,
            marker='o', color='red', scatter_kws={'s':20})
```

[image: big points]

Answer (score 17):

You could even make the points dynamically sized to represent a third dimension. This code uses the same data as the OP, but wraps it in a DataFrame (as seaborn is designed for that) and also adds a third dimension, z.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [x for x in range(5)],
    'y': [1, 3, 4, 2, 5],
    'z': [14, 14, 100, 16, 36]
})
sns.regplot(x='x', y='y', data=data, marker='o', color='red',
    scatter_kws={'s': data['z']})
```

You can probably imagine how you could also manipulate the list/array of sizes programatically, giving you a lot of power to convey extra information.

[image: straightforward version]

If you wanted to split these up into two groups, like in a FacetGrid, regplot doesn't handle that keyword mapping cleanly. But scatterplot does. Just plot regplot underneath for the fit line, then scatterplot over it for the points. Below, I've added a grp variable and plotted it onto a FacetGrid.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [x for x in range(5)],
    'y': [1, 3, 4, 2, 5],
    'z': [14, 14, 100, 16, 36],
    'grp': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'],
})
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=data, col='grp', margin_titles=True)
g.map_dataframe(sns.regplot, 'x', 'y', color='red', scatter=False)
g.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot, 'x', 'y', size='z', marker='o', color='red')
```

[image: facetgrid version]

Comment: This I believe is the most useful answer

Comment: Agreed with @Vivek, this is the more dynamic scaling I was looking for! 

Follow-up for @mightypile -- do you know how one could implement this dynamic scaling when plotting multiple facets on the same grid by hue? For instance,  if `group` is partitioned across your original data frame, something like `sns.regplot(x='x', y='y', data=data, hue = 'group', scatter_kws={'s': data['z']})`.

Comment: @El- I thought your question would be better as a separate question, then noticed your separate question got flagged as a duplicate, without addressing the facetgrid. See the additional edits to this question.

Answer (score 5):

I would add to mburke05's answer that it appears possible to pass array-like data into `scatter_kws.` For example, if you wanted the `size` attribute in the tips dataset to determine the size of a point you can write:

```
sns.regplot(
    x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips,
    marker='o', color='red', scatter_kws={'s':tips['size']})
```

However, you must explicitly lookup that attribute in the dataframe (as above); you cannot simply use the column name as you would when setting `x` and `y`.